# How to handle abnormal TCP disconnections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

The situation is that I used Node.js to start up a `TCP` and a `HTTP` server. The first one aimed at connecting with hardwares through TCP connection.

I have 100 TCP clients and keep their connection with the server alive.

In the normal situation, the TCP client will disconnect with the TCP server through four-way handshakes.

I met the problem that some clients in the 100 ones disconnected with the server through abnormal way like something wrong in the Ethernet cable or cut off, and didn't disconnect with the server through the normal way, then the tcp server was hang up, and I couldn't know which one has disconnected, while the `http server` is well. So I couldn't use the tcp server to connect with hardware clients.

I try to `try/catch` the error, but it didn't work it.

Comment: Maybe a timeout issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well.

Just need to use socket.on('error', fn) to listen the error event just be ok.